# Flutter FocusNode : Auto Focus is not working in my flutter app

Tags: flutter, flutter-textinputfield, flutter-focus-node

I want the Auto focus FocusNode in my OTP text fields.
I tried :
1st 2 field are working fine but after fill the 2nd field the curser move to 4th field after that is stopped.
The Issue:
The curser not moving automatically to 3rd and 5th text field.
[image: My OTP controller]

[image: My OTP text field]

[image: My UI screen]

[image: Output/ UI screen]

Comment: When i start typing from 2nd text field the its filling only these fields:
 2nd 3nd and 5th and then 1st,